# How to create a database link having ampersand(&) in the password

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

As the title says. Is there any way to create a database link with an ampersand password without changing the schema password?

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK DBLINK_NAME
CONNECT TO SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY p&ssword 
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host.name.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=host)))';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using set escape on and escaping the ampersand

```
SET ESCAPE ON;
CREATE DATABASE LINK DBLINK_NAME
CONNECT TO SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY p\&ssword 
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host.name.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=host)))';
```

Comment: "set escape on;" that was the part I was originally missing... My immediate response to your original question was to escape it with backslash as well "\", but both SQLPlus and SQLDev were still asking for the substitution value (whether or not I enclosed the password in double quotes)... so I figured I would just play along and supply the substitution value, :)

Answer (score 1):

Ampersand in the password is tricky because it is the define character, which you can view via:

```
show define;
```

You should be able to circumvent this by enclosing the password in quotes, then when you are asked to "Enter the Substitution Variable", enter the ampersand and the trailing characters like the following:

```
SQL> CREATE DATABASE LINK DBLINK_NAME
CONNECT TO SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY "p&ssword" 
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host.name.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=host)))';

Enter value for ssword: &ssword

old    1:      CREATE DATABASE LINK DBLINK_NAME
    CONNECT TO SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY "p&ssword" 
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host.name.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=host)))';
new    1:     CREATE DATABASE LINK DBLINK_NAME
    CONNECT TO SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY "p&ssword" 
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host.name.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=host)))';

Database link created.
```